# Google Ads not showing up on website which is a mern app

Tags: mern, adsense

So my website tab.pledgeasmile.com is not showing ads.
I am from a commerce background so don't know much about this. Can anyone take a look and help?

Comment: So we are using react and that is causing problems. if this helps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.